# Servlet image filter doesn't work on online host

Tags: java, image, servlets, filter, openshift

I'm learning Servlet. Today I tried to make a Servlet Filter, following a tutorial, the idea is:

- I have a default photo - notFound.jpg
- The filter will catch all image request, *.jpg *.png *.gif ...
- If file exists, return it, otherwise return notFound.jpg

Everything works just fine on my local (I'm using Eclipse and Tomcat 8).

But when i run it on an online host - Openshift, which runs Tomcat 7, I couldn't access any photo:

+In htm files, photos are displayed as source not found

+All absolute url to photos now pointing to notFound.jpg, and notFound.jpg itself doesn't return anything, just a blank page.

I think the problem is I couldn't get the realPath (request.getServletContext().getRealPath("");) on an online host, but I can't solve this problem.

Thank you so much for reading this

This is my Filter:

@WebFilter(urlPatterns = { "*.png", "*.jpg", "*.gif" }, 
initParams = {

@WebInitParam(name = "notFoundImage", value = "/img/notFound.jpg") })

public class ImageFilter implements Filter {

```
private String notFoundImage;

public ImageFilter() {
}

public void destroy() {
}

public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;

    String servletPath = req.getServletPath();

    String realRootPath = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("");

    String imageRealPath = realRootPath + servletPath;

    File file = new File(imageRealPath);

    if (file.exists()) {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    } else if (!servletPath.equals(this.notFoundImage)) {

        HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) response;

        resp.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath() + this.notFoundImage);
    }

}

public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {
    notFoundImage = fConfig.getInitParameter("notFoundImage");
}
```

}

Comment: Where are your images? On the server or package with the war file? Try print out the "real image path" and see if it exist on the server. I suspect you haven't deploy your images?

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, my photos are packed in the .war file. If I remove the annotation declaring this filter, then photos can be accessed normarly.  When i print realPath it returns null. Bạn là người Việt phải ko :D ?

Comment: pls help, I still can't solve this problem

Comment: Yes@Liberty. What is the directory structure in the war where your images located?